# How to install ioncube Loader in OpenShift with WorkFlow Guide

Tags: openshift, ioncube

I create an Application with following cartridges
 - PHP 5.4
 - MySQL 5.5
 - Phpmyadmin 4.0

What is the full workflow to make the ioncube fully function, and each time I push the repo data won't not deleted / reset?

I do read about
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-install-ioncube-loader

But not really clear for the step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to cdaley: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-install-ioncube-loader

1. First, you have to have created a gear with the **Zend cartridge**. (why? because you can go to zend/configuration/etc/php.ini to add the php.ini setting)
2. `ssh` into your gear and `cd app-root/data`
3. `wget http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz`
4. `tar -xvzf ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz`
5. You will end up with a
   folder called 'ioncube'
6. Run `echo $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` and make note of the output
7. `nano $HOME/zend/configuration/etc/php.ini`
8. Add this line to the END of the file you are editing (this one depend your php version, can be 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 or even latest version)

   `zend_extension=<OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR>ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so`

   Where you replace  with the path from Step 6.
9. Put the `loader-wizard.php` into your `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/php` directory
10. Exit out of your ssh connection
11. Run `rhc app restart $appname` where $appname is the name of your application OR you can restart on the web console.
12. View the $appname-$domain.rhcloud.com/loader-wizard.php in your browser and it should say that the extension is installed correctly now.